# Verb at the end of the sentence

Tags: verb

Why the word *"gehört"* is at end of the sentence?

> Solche Unreinheiten erwartet man niemals von jemandem, der zur zivilisierten Klasse der Menschen, den Āryas, **gehört**.

Comment: Because *…, der … gehört.* is a dependent, in this case a relative clause. Dependent clauses have their finite verb last in German (apart from exceptions, of course).

Comment: @Janka I know it's tempting, but please don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: I think this question can be easily answered by reading a basic German grammar book and should be closed.

Comment: Do you understand the sentence? What word order would you have expected? Why?

Comment: @Carsten, the sequence I expect is  as we are accustomed to, in English. "..who **belongs** to the civilised class of men, the Aryas."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the part

> ..., der zur zivilisierten Klasse der Menschen, den Āryas, gehört.

is a relative clause. It starts with a relative pronoun (der = which).

A very important rule for relative clauses is, that the verbs **MUST** stand at the end of the relative clause.

A main clause witch is related to this relative clause is:

> Der gehört zur zivilisierten Klasse der Menschen, den Āryas.

Here the verb ist at position 2, and at Position 1 you find the subject, which here is no longer a relative pronoun, but a demonstrative pronoun (der = this one).

The word *der* can appear in both rules, but you will see the difference, when you try to replace it with other pronouns:

> Relative clause: ..., **welcher** zur zivilisierten Klasse der Menschen, den Āryas, gehört.
>   Main clause: **Dieser** gehört zur zivilisierten Klasse der Menschen, den Āryas.

---

### Addendum

(reaction to a comment)

There are several types of sentences and several types of verbs:

1. Statements which are full clauses

   - If there is only one verb in the predicate, and if it is non-separable, it must stand at position 2 and it must be inflected to match with the subject in person and number.

     > Werner **schreibt** Briefe.
   - If the verb is separable, the main part must stand at position 2 and has to be inflected, the prefix has to be split off and has to stand at the end.

     > Werner **wäscht** das Geschirr **ab.**
   - If you have a full verb and an auxiliary verb, the auxiliary verb must stand at position 2 and must be inflected. The full verb stands at the end and must not be inflected (and it must not be split)

     > Werner **wird** das Geschirr **abwaschen.**
   - What has been said about auxiliary verbs is true for modal verbs too:

     > Werner **darf** das Geschirr **abwaschen.**
   - If you have full verb + auxiliary verb + modal verb, then the auxiliary verb has to stand at position 2 (and has to be inflected). At the end you have the full verb, followed by the modal verb (both not inflected)

     > Werner **wird** das Geschirr **abwaschen dürfen.**
2. Statements wich are relative clauses (here: a reason for something else)

   - Only a full verb: at the end, not separated, but inflected.

     > *<sup>Er hat keine Zeit, weil</sup>* Werner das Geschirr **abwäscht.**
   - Auxiliary verb + full verb: Full verb at the end (not inflected), followed by inflected auxiliary verb

     > *<sup>Er wird keine Zeit haben, weil</sup>* Werner das Geschirr **abwaschen wird.**
   - Modal verb + full verb: Same as auxiliary + full

     > *<sup>Er hat keine Zeit, weil</sup>* Werner das Geschirr **abwaschen darf.**
   - Modal + auxiliary + full: All three at the end, the order is: full, modal, auxiliary, only the auxiliary verb has to be inflected

     > *<sup>Er wird keine Zeit haben, weil</sup>* Werner das Geschirr **abwaschen dürfen wird.**
3. Closed Questions (to be answered with *yes* or *no*)

   - Only a non-separabe full verb: Put it at position 1 and inflect it

     > **Schreibt** Werner einen Brief?
   - A separable verb: But the main part at position 1 and inflect it. The prefix has to stand at the end.

     > **Wäscht** Werner das Geschirr **ab?**
   - additional auxiliary verb: The auxiliary Verb has to stand at position 1 and has to be inflected, the full verb goes to the end and is not inflected.

     > **Wird** Werner das Geschirr **abwaschen?**
   - Modal verb behaves like auxiliary verb

     > **Darf** Werner das Geschirr **abwaschen?**
   - All three kids of verbs: The auxiliary verb stands at position 1 and has to be inflected. At the end you have the full verb followed by the modal verb (both not inflected, and separable verbs are not split)

     > **Wird** Werner das Geschirr **abwaschen dürfen?**

Comment: Thank you but how can we explain the trailing position of the verb in below sentence.  (Positioning of verpflichtet  and annehmen)                                             Bhīṣma und Droṇa waren wegen Duryodhanas finanzieller Hilfe verpflichtet, sich auf seine Seite zu stellen, wenngleich sie eine solche Stellung, nur aufgrund finanzieller Überlegungen, nicht hätten annehmen sollen.

Comment: @Jim: Both *verplichtet* and *annehmen* are participles. In combination with auxiliaries as *sein* and *haben*, they are always trailing. You really need a German grammar book.

Comment: @Janka, I have the Hammer &  Smith, do you advise any other book?

Comment: Hammer's German grammar is a decent book. I don't know what's inside Brian Smith's "Power Reader Super Grammar". Oh, and I was wrong, *annehmen* is of course an inifinitive in the modal expression with *sollen*. It doesn't make a difference for the positioning however.